# Element wise multiplication of two arrays in C/C++

Tags: c++, std, c++14, multiplication, valarray

I would like to perform Element wise multiplication of two arrays, both are of type complex but I am getting the following error message:

```
serge@ubuntu:~/Downloads/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.9/build$ g++ -o myfft  myfft.cpp -std=c++14
In file included from myfft.cpp:14:0:
cs_delay.cpp: In function ‘void cs_delay(CArray&, int, int, int)’:
cs_delay.cpp:35:28: error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand types are ‘void’ and ‘Complex {aka std::complex}’)
         x[j] = ifft(fft(x) * rot[j]);
                            ^
cs_delay.cpp:35:28: note: candidates are:
In file included from myfft.cpp:1:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/complex:381:5: note: template std::complex std::operator*(const std::complex&, const std::complex&)
     operator*(const complex& __x, const complex& __y)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/complex:381:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from myfft.cpp:14:0:
cs_delay.cpp:35:35: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::complex’ and ‘void’
         x[j] = ifft(fft(x) * rot[j]);
                                   ^
In file included from myfft.cpp:1:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/complex:390:5: note: template std::complex std::operator*(const std::complex&, const _Tp&)
     operator*(const complex& __x, const _Tp& __y)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/complex:390:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from myfft.cpp:14:0:
cs_delay.cpp:35:35: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::complex’ and ‘void’
         x[j] = ifft(fft(x) * rot[j]);
                                   ^
In file included from myfft.cpp:1:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/complex:399:5: note: template std::complex std::operator*(const _Tp&, const std::complex&)
     operator*(const _Tp& __x, const complex& __y)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/complex:399:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from myfft.cpp:14:0:
cs_delay.cpp:35:35: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_Tp’ (‘void’ and ‘double’)
         x[j] = ifft(fft(x) * rot[j]);
                                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/valarray:587:0,
                 from myfft.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/valarray_after.h:404:5: note: template std::_Expr, typename std::__fun::result_type> std::operator*(const std::_Expr&, const std::_Expr&)
     _DEFINE_EXPR_BINARY_OPERATOR(*, __multiplies)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/valarray_after.h:404:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from myfft.cpp:14:0:
cs_delay.cpp:35:35: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::_Expr’ and ‘void’
         x[j] = ifft(fft(x) * rot[j]);
                                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/valarray:587:0,
                 from myfft.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/valarray_after.h:404:5: note: template std::_Expr, typename std::__fun::result_type> std:
```

Function which returns error :

```
//cs_delay.cpp
using namespace std;

typedef std::complex<double> Complex;
typedef std::valarray<Complex> CArray;


void cs_delay(CArray& x, int rate_hz, int delay_s, int n)
{

const size_t N = x.size();
    if (N <= 1) return;

int j;
double cycLen_s;
double nCyc;
double* f = new double[n];
double* phase = new double[n];
Complex* rot = new Complex[n];
cycLen_s = n/rate_hz;
nCyc = delay_s / cycLen_s;
/*************************************************************/
for ( j = 0 ; j < n ; j++ ){

        f[j] =j+floor(n/2);
        f[j] =fmod(f[j], n);
        f[j] =f[j]-floor(n/2);
        phase[j] = -2 * PI * f[j] * nCyc;
        rot[j] = exp(1i*phase[j]);
        std::cout << "rot["<<j<<"] ="<<rot[j] <<std::endl;
        fft(x);
        x *= rot[j];
        ifft(x);
        }
/*************************************************************/
        delete [] f;
        delete [] phase;
        delete [] rot;
}
```

fft and ifft are here:

```
//fft.cpp
using namespace std;
const double PI = 3.141592653589793238460;


//functions declarations

typedef std::complex<double> Complex;
typedef std::valarray<Complex> CArray;
// Cooley–Tukey FFT (in-place, divide-and-conquer)
// Higher memory requirements and redundancy although more intuitive
void fft(CArray& x)
{
    const size_t N = x.size();
    if (N <= 1) return;

    // divide
    CArray even = x[std::slice(0, N/2, 2)];
    CArray  odd = x[std::slice(1, N/2, 2)];

    // conquer
    fft(even);
    fft(odd);

    // combine
    for (size_t k = 0; k < N/2; ++k)
    {
        Complex t = std::polar(1.0, -2 * PI * k / N) * odd[k];
        x[k    ] = even[k] + t;
        x[k+N/2] = even[k] - t;
    }
}
// inverse fft (in-place)
void ifft(CArray& x)

{
    // conjugate the complex numbers
    x = x.apply(std::conj);

    // forward fft
    fft( x );

    // conjugate the complex numbers again
    x = x.apply(std::conj);

    // scale the numbers
    x /= x.size();
}
```

here is my main function:

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include "fft.cpp"
#include "cs_delay.cpp"
using namespace std;
//const double PI  = 3.141592653589793238460;
char filename[]  = "vidres6.txt";
char filename2[] = "vidres7.txt";

//typedef std::complex<double> Complex;
//typedef std::valarray <Complex> CArray;
/***********************************************************************************************
*                                 function declarations
************************** ******************************************************** ***********/
void fft(CArray& x);
void ifft(CArray& x);
void binFreq(int n);
void cs_delay(CArray& x, int rate_hz, int delay_s, int n);

int main()

{
        int dTest_samples;
        int cTest;
        //cTest = -cTest;  
        int n=299;
        int i;
        int j;
        double x [n];

    /*****************************getting x*******************************/

        string line;
        double Result;
             ifstream myfile (filename);
             if (myfile.is_open())
               {
                 for ( i = 0 ; (i < n) && (myfile >> x[i]) ; ++i)

                        cout << line << '\n';
                         stringstream convert(line);

                         if ( !(convert >> Result) )
                        Result = 0;
                        x[i]=Result;


               }
                else cout << "Unable to open file";
    /***********************************************************************/


    Complex test[n];

    for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i )
    test[i] = x[i];

    CArray data(test,n);

    // forward fft
    fft(data);

    std::cout << "fft" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <n; ++i)
    {
        cout << data[i] << endl;
    }

    // inverse fft
    ifft(data);

    std::cout << std::endl << "ifft" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <n; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fft` does not return anything (it returns `void`) but you are trying to multiply the result by something ("`fft(x) * rot[j]`"). This is not going to work.

On the same line, you assign the result of `ifft` to `x[j]`, but `ifft` also does not return anything.

Assuming that `fft` and `ifft` are modifying their arguments in-place correctly, try replacing the line

```
x[j] = ifft(fft(x) * rot[j]);
```

by

```
fft(x);
x *= rot[j];
ifft(x);
```

Comment: I have made the change and now I am getting this :cs_delay.cpp: In function ‘void cs_delay(CArray&, int, int, int)’:
cs_delay.cpp:32:16: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘CArray& {aka std::valarray<std::complex<double> >&}’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::_Expr<std::_BinClos<std::__multiplies, std::_ValArray, std::_Constant, std::complex<double>, std::complex<double> >, std::complex<double> >’
         ifft(x * rot[j]);
                ^
In file included from myfft.cpp:13:0:
fft.cpp:46:6: note: in passing argument 1 of ‘void ifft(CArray&)’
 void ifft(CArray& x)

Comment: @Serge: Ah, that's because `x * rot[j]` is a temporary, and can't be passed as a non-const reference. Try this change.

Comment: That seems to work , I am not getting error any more thanks!!! On last thing , How  could I retrieve the result of ifft(x) so that I can use it later in my program?  , I was thinking about something like x=ifft(x), can I do that ?

Comment: @Serge, `ifft` _does not return anything_. `x=ifft(x)` is meaningless, because `ifft(x)` does not have any value. But it _modifies its argument_, so after calling `ifft(x)`, `x` has changed.